# jQuery onchange detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I want to execute javascript that's in the "onchange" attribute of an html element. So..

```
<input id="el" type="text" onchange="alert('test');" value="" />
```

Using that example I'd like to execute the al`ert('test');` portion via jQuery, the problem is the `.change()` event handler isn't working, because I want to execute it after another element changes it's value. So..

```
$('#el').val('test');
```

This is when I'd like to execute the onchange. After that `.val` val has been called. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please add more descriptions of which elements or what code you are talking about? It's easier to read `the first element, which has an onchange attribute` than just `the other element`.

Comment: Avoid using inline JavaScript. Attach the change handler using jQuery, and it will be easier to manage.

Answer (score 7):

`.val()` does not trigger `change` events. You need to do so yourself, manually. For example:

```
$('#el').val('test').change();
```

You can encapsulate this in a small jQuery plugin like so:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.changeVal = function (text) {
        this.val(text).change();
    };
}(jQuery));

$('#el').changeVal('test');
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it makes sense that the onchange event ALWAYS fires when the value of the field changes.  Thus, I would change the `val` function in JQuery itself rather than make a custom function.  That way, you don't have to worry about which function you use to set the value of an object, and don't have to go change all of your `val` calls if you've already used JQuery to code your app.  Here's the code:

```
//Store the old val function
$.fn.custom_oldVal = $.fn.val;

//Update the val function to fire the change event where appropriate:
$.fn.val = function(value) {
    if(value == null || value == undefined){
        return this.custom_oldVal();
    } else {
        //Only call onchange if the value has changed
        if(value == this.custom_oldVal()){
            return this;//Return this object for chain processing
        } else {
            return this.custom_oldVal(value).change();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a while ago, but couldn't find any good solutions to it. It seems the best solution is to do a "pull" on the input, or to fire your onchange function (like Domenic shows) from the code that actually changes the content of the input.

Answer (score 0):

if you first
`input.focus();` then `$.val('abcd');` a change event will be fired.
*taken from jquery site*.

Answer (score -1):

I Would redesign and start using [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) plugin which is using data-bind where let u use all the binding pretty easy.

sample code below:

```
var ViewModel = function(first, last) {
this.firstName = ko.observable(first);
this.lastName = ko.observable(last);

this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
    // Knockout tracks dependencies automatically. It knows that fullName depends on firstName and lastName, because these get called when evaluating fullName.
    return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
}, this);
```

};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Planet", "Earth"));