# Detect if the value of a text input changes with no event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking to get the value of this input if it changes. I have a map.swf that makes the value change depending on what the user selects in the .swf, so I was wondering how to get this done.

```
<a href="map.php" onclick='return GB_showCenter("",this.href,380,780);' class="page">See Map</a>
<input name="sector_e" type="text" id="sector_e" value="Please click The Map" size="1" readonly>
```

This jQuery only alerts me if I press a key, I want it to alert if the value changes without any event.

```
$('#sector_e').bind("keyup", function() {    
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'without any event'. How will you know, without events, when the value changes?

Comment: Here are some solutions from a previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349504/jquery-onchange-detection

Comment: If one of these answers works be sure to mark the checkbox next to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do a combination of things:

1. Use jQuery's [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) command capabilities to save the initial value.
2. Use the jQuery's [`focusout`](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) or [`blur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) or [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event to check the current value against what is saved using `data`.

Which even you choose depends on whether or not direct user-interaction is possible or not. Further processing can happen once you detect a change.

**FOR EXAMPLE:**
You might consider marking the element with a class name like "isDirty" using jQuery's [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) command.

Then you could do things like:

```
$('.isDirty')
```

In the meantime...

**HERE IS A CODE SAMPLE USING FOCUSOUT:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var txtSectorE = $('#sector_e');

        // Save the initial value
        $.data(txtSectorE, "last", txtSectorE.val());

        // Setup the event
        txtSectorE.focusout(function () {
            var last = $.data(txtSectorE, "last");
            if (last != $(this).val())
                alert("changed");
        });
    });
</script>

<input id="sector_e" name="sector_e" type="text" value="Please click The Map">
```

Of course, doing it this way is taxing as you would have to write a separate set of calls for each `textbox`.

So, why not add a class name to each `textbox` and do it this way...

**A BETTER EXAMPLE USING FOCUSOUT:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var txtSectors = $('.sector');

            $.each(txtSectors, function (index, textbox) {

                // Save the initial value
                $.data(textbox, "last", textbox.val());

                // Setup the event
                textbox.focusout(function () {
                    var element = $(this);
                    var last = $.data(element, "last");
                    if (last != element.val())
                        alert("changed");
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

<input id="sector_a" type="text" class="sector" value="Something">
<input id="sector_b" type="text" class="sector" value="Another">
<input id="sector_c" type="text" class="sector" value="Yet Again">
<input id="sector_d" type="text" class="sector" value="Wow This Arduous">
<input id="sector_e" type="text" class="sector" value="Getting Tired Of Typing">
```

Answer (score 1):

The event "change" should do what you want :)

```
 $('#sector_e').bind("change", function() {

           alert($(this).val()); 

     });
```

edit:
To make this work, the swf must also trigger the change event.

If this is not possible, you can check every n milliseconds if the value has change and trigger the change event in this case.

```
var checkChange function($object){
    var currentValue = $object.val();

    var checkChanges = function() {
        if (checkChanges.val() != currentValue) {
            currentValue = checkChanges.val();
            $object.trigger("change");
        }
    }

    window.setInterval(checkChanges, 100);
}

checkChange($('#sector_e'));
```

Comment: That's not going to do anything if the value is set in code. He'll have to trigger the event.

Comment: yeah ur right i can see the value text change but i get no alert any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: Yeah, you're right… The swf must also trigger the change event to make it work.

Comment: any example how to trigger the change in swf?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no event triggered when the value of the text input changes (Via SWF or JS).
A solution is to use a timer to constantly check for the value of the text input. If it is different that than the previously stored value is has changed and then you can do your thing.

(Far from optimal but a solution)

See here for an implementation: [I want to trigger an event every single time data changes in an HTML text input field regardless of focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835337/i-want-to-trigger-an-event-every-single-time-data-changes-in-an-html-text-input)

```
setInterval( function() {
    $('input').each( function() {
        if ($(this).val() != $(this).data("_value")) {
            // Save the new value
            var myVal =  $(this).val();
            $(this).data("_value",myval);

            // TODO - Handle the changed value
        }
    });
}, 100);
```

From @Plutor