# jQuery Retrieving and Comparing Text Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, input

I tried to use **jQuery** to check if the value of a text input has changed, and if so if it matches a predefined word. I've tried to use `.focusout()` to detect change, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035687/detect-if-the-value-of-a-text-input-changes-with-no-event) advises, with no success. I was able to detect a change, but I was unable to compare that change to the predefined word. Is it possible to do this with jQuery, and if so, how?

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var code = $('#code');

   // Save the initial value
   $.data(code, "last", code.val());

   // Setup the event
   code.focusout(function() {
     var last = $.data(code, "last");
     if (last != $(this).val())
       alert("changed");
     var value = $("#code").attr('value');
     if (value === "CODE") {
       $(".upper").slideUp(1000);
       $(".lower").slideUp(1000);
       $(".main").css({
         left: -1000
       });
       $(".test").css({
         color: green
       }); //Testing Property
     }
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" placeholder="ENTER" class="input" id="code">

<p class="test">Does it work?</p>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `.attr('value')`, just use `.val()`

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var code = $('#code');

   // Save the initial value
   $.data(code, "last", code.val());

   // Setup the event
   code.focusout(function() {
     var last = $.data(code, "last");
     if (last != $(this).val())
       alert("changed");
     var value = $("#code").val();
     if (value === "CODE") {
       alert("CODE!");
       $(".upper").slideUp(1000);
       $(".lower").slideUp(1000);
       $(".main").css({
         left: -1000
       });
       $(".test").css({
         color: green
       }); //Testing Property
     }
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" placeholder="ENTER" class="input" id="code">

<p class="test">Does it work?</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! That was so simple, I can't believe I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `last` value again if the value has changed. And you didn't specify any starting value, so your starting value will be empty.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var code = $('#code');

   // Save the initial value
   $.data(code, "last", code.val());

   // Setup the event
   code.focusout(function() {
     var last = $.data(code, "last");
     if (last != $(this).val()){
       $.data(code, "last", code.val());
       alert("changed");
     }
     var value = $("#code").attr('value');
     if (value === "CODE") {
       $(".upper").slideUp(1000);
       $(".lower").slideUp(1000);
       $(".main").css({
         left: -1000
       });
       $(".test").css({
         color: green
       }); //Testing Property
     }
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" placeholder="ENTER" class="input" id="code">

<p class="test">Does it work?</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var code = $('#code');
 var lastWord = ""; 

   // Setup the event
   code.focusout(function() {
     var value = $("#code").attr('value');
     if(value === lastWord){
      alert("No change");
     }else{
      alert("Change")
     }
     lastWord = value;
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" placeholder="ENTER" class="input" id="code">

<p class="test">Does it work?</p>
```

Basically you start with an empty string as your 'last code', then on focus out, you compare your value to your lastWord, if those matches, there wasn't any change. When you are done comparing, you set your lastWord to your value.

Comment: Why am I getting downvoted :(, I provided a reasonable answer with a functional script that works exactly like the OP had problem with...